# How to find a model for dataset

Tags: python, r

I have a text file that contains dates and numerical values like

```
1.1.2020, 45.67
2.1.2020, 49.65
4.1.2020, 47.58
31.1.2020, 55.88
...
```

Note that value of some dates is missing.

I would like to fit a model of the form ae^(bx) to find an estimate what would be value in 1.1.2021. How can I do that? Is there some Sagemath function for that or some Python library to find such a model.

Comment: [Fitting a equation to a set of data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/595913) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For your specified formula, this can be solved by fitting a log-log model.

> Y = a * exp(b*x)
>
> log(Y) = log(a) + b*x

1. Transform your dates into numeric type (for ex. `as.numeric()`)
2. Fit an ordinary linear model
3. Back transform the results onto the original scale

> Y = exp(intercept + slope*date)

In R, using some made up data

```
dates=sort(sample(1:100,20))
values=exp(seq(0,5,length.out=20))+rnorm(20)

mod=lm(log(values)~dates)

new=1:100
plot(values~dates)
points(exp(coef(mod)[1]+coef(mod)[2]*new)~new,col="red")
```